# Create dict in one module and access it in another module through multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am new to python and multiprocessing concepts in python (this is my first python project).

I have written few modules and wired them up together to work in sequential manner. Right now, i have requirement to fasten few things.

What i want to achieve is:

```
module-one.py
    Read a json and store it as dict (normal dict or multiprocessing.Manager.dict)
    module-two.method()
    
module-two.py
    -- Some methods for business logic --
    multiprocessing.process(target=module-three.method)
    
module-three.py
    def method():
        multiprocessing.process(target=module-four.method)
        
module-four.py
    def method():
        I should access the dict that was created in module-one
        The global dict that mutiple processes can access
        --- More business logic and data transformations ---
        
Note:
    I am constrained not to use any frameworks like Flask. Else, i could have tried flask g to store things globally.
    I am constrained not to use any external caching mechanisms like memcache or redis
```

To lessen the overhead, i tried combining the modules three and four into one. That also did not help. The dict in module-four or module-three is always empty.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to achieve what i have posted above?
2. If it is not possible, what are the alternate ways to handle my requirements.

I browsed extensively stackoverflow and other forums. I found many single module examples where dict is created at module namespace or inside a class and same dict is passed as an argument to spawning processes. Based on those examples, it looks like i should pass the dict from module-one to module-two and so on upto module-four. I felt that there might be a better approach instead of passing the dict from one module to another. Hence i am posting this question.

Thanks,
A newbie python coder

Comment: It would help a lot if you share the code, it's not quite clear to me what you wanna do.

Comment: have you tried the `multiprocessing.shared_memory` module?

Comment: The easiest way to share a dictionary across processes is with a *managed* dictionary, e.g. `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()`. But be aware of the overhead of each access and some of its peculiarities.

Comment: @constt
I do not have the code in the system from where i am posting the question as all the development happens in secure network and we do not have access to internet in that machine. I will try to write something simple and post it

Comment: @alexpdev No, i have not tried shared_memory. I will check that.

Comment: @Booboo I read about that and saw many examples. I should pass the created `multiprocessing.Manager().dict()` as an argument to the spawning processes. Is there an option where i can access it without passing it as an argument. The question may sound dumb. Please note that i am trying to learn python and get a hang of how things work in python.

Comment: @Strive The response is too long for a comment, so see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can avoid having to pass the managed dictionary explicitly to your worker function, which can now instead access it as a global variable:

Both `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` and `concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor` have *initializer* and *initargs* arguments that allow you to specify a function and arguments to be passed to that function that will be called once for *each* process in the multiprocessing pool to allow that function to initialize global variables for each process. So, for example, using `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, the following code will work for both Windows and Linux:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def init_pool_processes(d):
    # Initialize global variable managed_dict for each pool process:
    global managed_dict
    managed_dict = d

def worker(i):
    managed_dict[i] = i ** 2

def main():
    manager = Manager()
    managed_dict = manager.dict()
    pool = Pool(initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(managed_dict,))
    pool.map(worker, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(managed_dict)

if __name__ == '__main__': # Required for Windows
    main()
```

Prints:

```None
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 8: 64, 9: 81}
```

If you are running under a platform such as Linux that uses the *fork* method to create new processes, then those new processes would inherit the main processes global variables automatically as read/only variables. Once an attempt is made to modify such a variable by the subprocess, then a copy of that variable is made. However, in this case, the global variable in question is a reference to a managed dictionary (actually, a reference to a *proxy* for the actual dictionary) and this reference is not modified by the subprocesses, only what the reference refers to, i.e. the dictionary itself. So the following code would be used:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager

def worker(i):
    managed_dict[i] = i ** 2

def main():
    global managed_dict
    manager = Manager()
    managed_dict = manager.dict()
    # the processes created will inherit global managed_dict:
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(worker, range(10))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print(managed_dict)

main()
```

Prints:

```None
{0: 0, 8: 64, 9: 81, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 5: 25, 6: 36, 7: 49, 4: 16}
```

This is why when you post a question tagged with `multiprocessing`, you are supposed to also tag the question with the platform you are running under; the answer very much depends on the platform.